Guy tortured with feet in boiling water?
It's an "old" movie from 90s or 80s. A guy is on the run from either gangsters or casino owners or bounty hunters employed by them. I think he stole or won too much money. Money or maybe even drugs.
Scenes I remember:

The guy is tortured by another guy with his feet in boiling water.
A woman saves him from the hospital afterwards (wheelchair, car).

I don't remember much. But I would like to watch it again. Hope someone can help me out with the title.

This sounds like Night of the Running Man:

To quote from the Wiki description:

Jerry Logan, a cab driver in Las Vegas, picks up a nervous passenger who offers him $100 to get to the airport as quickly as possible.
  Unknown to Jerry, the man has stolen $1 million from the Al Chambers,
  a mob-connected casino owner.

Also:

With no other choices available, Logan chooses Mills' cab. Mills
  kidnaps him at gunpoint and, at his house, burns Logan's feet in
  boiling water to make escape impossible. However, Mills underestimates
  Logan, who is able to overpower him and flee with the money. When
  Logan collapses unconscious on the street, he is taken to the
  hospital, where he meets nurse Chris Altman. Altman treats his wounds
  and covers for him when Eckhart comes looking. Mills, who is in the
  same hospital, overhears that Altman has taken Logan to a hotel for
  safety, and he alerts Eckhart.

Note: "Nurse Chris Altman", despite the name suggesting otherwise, is female.

Yup, that's exactly it. I recognized quite a lot watching it again, though there was no wheelchair, not in the main action at least. But who says "Chris", "Altman" or "Nurse" is suggesting a male character? Whatever ... thanks!
